# Splitting a large data frame into smaller segments

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have the following data frame and I want to break it up into 10 different data frames. I want to break the initial 100 row data frame into 10 data frames of 10 rows. I could do the following and get the desired results.

```
df = data.frame(one=c(rnorm(100)), two=c(rnorm(100)), three=c(rnorm(100)))

df1 = df[1:10,]
df2 = df[11:20,]
df3 = df[21:30,]
df4 = df[31:40,]
df5 = df[41:50,]
...
```

Of course, this isn't an elegant way to perform this task when the initial data frames are larger or if there aren't an easy number of segments that it can be broken down into.

So given the above, let's say we have the following data frame.

```
df = data.frame(one=c(rnorm(1123)), two=c(rnorm(1123)), three=c(rnorm(1123)))
```

Now I want to split it into new data frames comprised of 200 rows, and the final data frame with the remaining rows. What would be a more elegant (aka 'quick') way to perform this task.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
 > str(split(df, (as.numeric(rownames(df))-1) %/% 200))
List of 6
 $ 0:'data.frame':  200 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ one  : num [1:200] -1.592 1.664 -1.231 0.269 0.912 ...
  ..$ two  : num [1:200] 0.639 -0.525 0.642 1.347 1.142 ...
  ..$ three: num [1:200] -0.45 -0.877 0.588 1.188 -1.977 ...
 $ 1:'data.frame':  200 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ one  : num [1:200] -0.0017 1.9534 0.0155 -0.7732 -1.1752 ...
  ..$ two  : num [1:200] -0.422 0.869 0.45 -0.111 0.073 ...
  ..$ three: num [1:200] -0.2809 1.31908 0.26695 0.00594 -0.25583 ...
 $ 2:'data.frame':  200 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ one  : num [1:200] -1.578 0.433 0.277 1.297 0.838 ...
  ..$ two  : num [1:200] 0.913 0.378 0.35 -0.241 0.783 ...
  ..$ three: num [1:200] -0.8402 -0.2708 -0.0124 -0.4537 0.4651 ...
 $ 3:'data.frame':  200 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ one  : num [1:200] 1.432 1.657 -0.72 -1.691 0.596 ...
  ..$ two  : num [1:200] 0.243 -0.159 -2.163 -1.183 0.632 ...
  ..$ three: num [1:200] 0.359 0.476 1.485 0.39 -1.412 ...
 $ 4:'data.frame':  200 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ one  : num [1:200] -1.43 -0.345 -1.206 -0.925 -0.551 ...
  ..$ two  : num [1:200] -1.343 1.322 0.208 0.444 -0.861 ...
  ..$ three: num [1:200] 0.00807 -0.20209 -0.56865 1.06983 -0.29673 ...
 $ 5:'data.frame':  123 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ one  : num [1:123] -1.269 1.555 -0.19 1.434 -0.889 ...
  ..$ two  : num [1:123] 0.558 0.0445 -0.0639 -1.934 -0.8152 ...
  ..$ three: num [1:123] -0.0821 0.6745 0.6095 1.387 -0.382 ...
```

If some code might have changed the rownames it would be safer to use:

```
 split(df, (seq(nrow(df))-1) %/% 200)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
require(ff)
df <- data.frame(one=c(rnorm(1123)), two=c(rnorm(1123)), three=c(rnorm(1123)))
for(i in chunk(from = 1, to = nrow(df), by = 200)){
  print(df[min(i):max(i), ])
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can generate a vector that defines the groups, you can `split` anything:

```
f <- rep(seq_len(ceiling(1123 / 200)),each = 200,length.out = 1123)
> df1 <- split(df,f = f)
> lapply(df1,dim)
$`1`
[1] 200   3

$`2`
[1] 200   3

$`3`
[1] 200   3

$`4`
[1] 200   3

$`5`
[1] 200   3

$`6`
[1] 123   3
```

Answer (score 5):

## Chops df into 1 million row groups and pushes and appends a million at a time to df in SQL

```
batchsize = 1000000 # vary to your liking

# cycles through data by batchsize
for (i in 1:ceiling(nrow(df)/batchsize)) 
 {
print(i) # just to show the progress

# below shows how to cycle through data 
batch <- df[(((i-1)*batchsize)+1(batchsize*i),,drop=FALSE] # drop = FALSE keeps it from being converted to a vector 

# if below not done then the last batch has Nulls above the number of rows of actual data
batch <- batch[!is.na(batch$ID),] # ID is a variable I presume is in every row

#in this case the table already existed, if new table overwrite = TRUE
(dbWriteTable(con, "df", batch, append = TRUE,row.names = FALSE)) 
}
```

Comment: Not sure why minus oned. This is an effective option

Comment: Changing the first batch to 
`batch <- df[(((i - 1)*batch_size) + 1):(batch_size*i), , drop = FALSE]`
worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Something like this...?

```
b <- seq(10, 100, 10)
lapply(seq_along(b), function(i) df[(b-9)[i]:b[i], ])

[[1]]
          one        two      three
1  -2.4157992 -0.6232517  1.0531358
2   0.6769020  0.3908089 -1.9543895
3   0.9804026 -2.5167334  0.7120919
4  -1.2200089  0.5108479  0.5599177
5   0.4448290 -1.2885275 -0.7665413
6   0.8431848 -0.9359947  0.1068137
7  -1.8168134 -0.2418887  1.1176077
8   1.4475904 -0.8010347  2.3716663
9   0.7264027 -0.3573623 -1.1956806
10  0.2736119 -1.5553148  0.2691115

[[2]]
          one         two       three
11 -0.3273536 -1.92475496 -0.08031696
12  1.5558892 -1.20158371  0.09104958
13  1.9202047 -0.13418754  0.32571632
14 -0.0515136 -2.15669216  0.23099397
15  0.1909732 -0.30802742 -1.28651457
16  0.8545580 -0.18238266  1.57093844
17  0.4903039  0.02895376 -0.47678196
18  0.5125400  0.97052082 -0.70541908
19 -1.9324370  0.22093545 -0.34436105
20 -0.5763433  0.10442551 -2.05597985

[[3]]
          one         two       three
21  0.7168771 -1.22902943 -0.18728871
22  1.2785641  0.14686576 -1.74738091
23 -1.1856173  0.43829361  0.41269975
24  0.0220843  1.57428924 -0.80163986
25 -1.0012255  0.05520813  0.50871603
26 -0.1842323 -1.61195239  0.04843504
27  0.2328831 -0.38432225  0.95650710
28  0.8821687 -1.32456215 -1.33367967
29 -0.8902177  0.86414661 -1.39629358
30 -0.6586293 -2.27325919  0.27367902

[[4]]
          one        two       three
31  1.3810437 -1.0178835  0.07779591
32  0.6102753  0.3538498  1.92316801
33 -1.5034439  0.7926925  2.21706284
34  0.8251638  0.3992922  0.56781321
35 -1.0832114  0.9878058 -0.16820827
36 -0.4132375 -0.9214491  1.06681472
37 -0.6787631  1.3497766  2.18327887
38 -3.0082585 -1.3047024 -0.04913214
39 -0.3433300  1.1008951 -2.02065141
40  0.6009334  1.2334421  0.15623298

[[5]]
          one         two       three
41 -1.8608051 -0.08589437  0.02370983
42 -0.1829953  0.91139017 -0.01356590
43  1.1146731  0.42384993 -0.68717391
44  1.9039900 -1.70218225  0.06100297
45 -0.4851939  1.38712015 -1.30613414
46 -0.4661664  0.23504099 -0.29335162
47  0.5807227 -0.87821946 -0.14816121
48 -2.0168910 -0.47657382  0.90503226
49  2.5056404  0.27574224  0.10326333
50  0.2238735  0.34441325 -0.17186115

[[6]]
           one        two      three
51  1.51613140 -2.5630782 -0.6720399
52  0.03859537 -2.6688365  0.3395574
53 -0.08695292 -0.5114117 -0.1378789
54 -0.51878363 -0.5401962  0.3946324
55 -2.20482710  0.1716744  0.1786546
56 -0.28133749 -0.4497112  0.5936497
57 -2.38269088 -0.4625695  1.0048914
58  0.37865952  0.5055141  0.3337986
59  0.09329172  0.1560469  0.2835735
60 -1.10818863 -0.2618910  0.3650042

[[7]]
          one        two       three
61 -1.2507208 -1.5050083 -0.63871084
62  0.1379394  0.7996674 -1.80196762
63  0.1582008 -0.3208973  0.40863693
64 -0.6224605  0.1416938 -0.47174711
65  1.1556149 -1.4083576 -1.12619693
66 -0.6956604  0.7994991  1.16073748
67  0.6576676  1.4391007  0.04134445
68  1.4610598 -1.0066840 -1.82981058
69  1.1951788 -0.4005535  1.57256648
70 -0.1994519  0.2711574 -1.04364396

[[8]]
           one        two       three
71  1.23897065  0.4473611 -0.35452535
72  0.89015916  2.3747385  0.87840852
73 -1.17339703  0.7433220  0.40232381
74 -0.24568490 -0.4776862  1.24082294
75 -0.47187443 -0.3271824  0.38542703
76 -2.20899136 -1.1131712 -0.33663075
77 -0.05968035 -0.6023045 -0.23747388
78  1.19687199 -1.3390960 -1.37884241
79 -1.29310506  0.3554548 -0.05936756
80 -0.17470891  1.6198307  0.69170207

[[9]]
           one         two       three
81 -1.06792315  0.04801998  0.08166394
82  0.84152560 -0.45793907  0.27867619
83  0.07619456 -1.21633682 -2.51290495
84  0.55895466 -1.01844178 -0.41887672
85  0.33825508 -1.15061381  0.66206732
86 -0.36041720  0.32808609 -1.83390913
87 -0.31595401 -0.87081019  0.45369366
88  0.92331087  1.22055348 -1.91048757
89  1.30491142  1.22582353 -1.32244004
90 -0.32906839  1.76467263  1.84479228

[[10]]
            one        two       three
91   2.80656707 -0.9708417  0.25467304
92   0.35770119 -0.6132523 -1.11467041
93   0.09598908 -0.5710063 -0.96412216
94  -1.08728715  0.3019572 -0.04422049
95   0.14317455  0.1452287 -0.46133199
96  -1.00218917 -0.1360570  0.88864256
97  -0.25316855  0.6341925 -1.37571664
98   0.36375921  1.2244921  0.12718650
99   0.13345555  0.5330221 -0.29444683
100  2.28548261 -2.0413222 -0.53209956
```