# How can I split a CSV file into small chunks?

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to split a CSV file into small chunks. I want to split by any number or rows.  Maybe 20, 1,000, or whatever.

```
setwd("C:/Users/my_path/test_folder/") 
mydata = read.csv("NHLData.csv") 


split(mydata, ceiling(seq_along(mydata)/20))
```

Error: Warning message: In split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) : data length is not a multiple of split variable

I also tried this.

```
split(mydata, ceiling(seq_along(mydata)/(length(mydata)/20)))
```

Same Error: Warning message: In split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) : data length is not a multiple of split variable

I Googled for those ideas.  I didn't really find anything else that was useful.  This must be pretty simple, right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164525/splitting-a-large-data-frame-into-smaller-segments has a few solutions

Comment: A combination of `skip` and `nrows` in `read.csv` will give you all you need to read in any rows of a csv file that you want...

Comment: Ryguy72(72), don't make multiple accounts. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to merge them.

Comment: Why doesn't he accept anything? Mark any of his questions as correct? Is that acceptable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a large data frame into smaller segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164525/splitting-a-large-data-frame-into-smaller-segments)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of 'sample' function, that would help.

```
setwd("C:/Users/my_path/test_folder/") 
mydata = read.csv("NHLData.csv") 

# If you want 5 different chunks with same number of lines, lets say 30.
Chunks = split(mydata,sample(rep(1:5,30)))  ## 5 Chunks of 30 lines each

# If you want 20 samples, put any range of 20 values within the range of number of rows
First_chunk <- sample(mydata[1:20,])  ## this would contain first 20 rows

# Or you can print any number of rows within the range
Second_chunk <- sample(mydata[100:70,] ## this would contain last 30 rows in reverse order if your data had 100 rows.

# If you want to write these chunks out in a csv file:
write.csv(First_chunk,file="First_chunk.csv",quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=T)
write.csv(Second_chunk,file="Second_chunk.csv",quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=T)
```

Hope this helped.