# Split a list into smaller parts for transformations (hoping to work around memory limitations)

Tags: r

There are several posts on splitting up a data frame into pieces e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145863/splitting-a-dataframe-into-equal-parts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164525/splitting-a-large-data-frame-into-smaller-segments).

I have a corpus of text data and as I understand it a corpus is a list. I'm struggling to run transformations on my corpus so wanted to try splitting it into pieces to loop over transformations rather than on the entire corpus at once.

```
> length(corpus)
[1] 1000 # sample small 1k corpus

> typeof(corpus)
[1] "list"

pieces <- split(corpus, 10)
```

My goal is to get a list of lists of length 100 each but after running the above line using `split()` pieces has length one and appears to have retained only the first document in the original data corpus.

How can I split my corpus into 10 parts like in the linked SO posts using e.g. split or another method?

Comment: Why don't you perform the split before importing documents into your Corpus and make a list of Corpora instead?

Comment: Yes, this is my backup plan. I was hoping there's a straightforwards way of doing it with the actual corpus first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the second argument of `split()` should be a vector. Have you tried `pieces <- split(corpus, 1:10)`?

Comment: Using 1:10 like you suggest does seem to return the first ten items in the list. My goal is to return e.g. ten lists of length 100 by splitting corpus into ten

Comment: Or maybe I have misunderstood split() ? Does ```split(corpus, 1:10)``` split the list into parts where each part is a tenth of the original list?

Comment: Yes, I think I misunderstood split function, you're right it needs a vector. Accepting, thanks for pointing out.